# Date Format changing while printing description

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting some date in this format "04/11/13 19:37:00" I want to convert this date to local time zone, Below is the code i am using.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"date value %@",date);
```

The Problem i am facing is i am using debugger when i place mouse on the "date" variable it is showing "**2013-04-12 01:07:00 IST**" This is the correct out put i need. But when i am printing the same "date" variable using NSLog i am getting "2013-04-11 19:37:00 +0000". How can i get the correct format can any one explay, Do i need to change the **dateformat**.

Comment: The description of NSDate will be always in UTC. You can see that IST time zone is 5.30 hours before UTC, so your date is correct.

Comment: How to convert the "2013-04-11 19:37:00 +0000" to local time zone "2013-04-12 01:07:00 IST" like this

Comment: I assume that the time you are getting is in GMT and then you want to convert the UTC to local time zone. If that's the case you can set the timezone to local in dateFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

`NSLog` shows `NSDate` objects in a fixed format. If you want to log the date in a specific format, convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` using an `NSDateFormatter` and then log the string.

Remember, logging a date is only for debugging purposes. The format in the log really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the dateString which was in UTC to Local Timezone, you need to do it in two steps.

1.First form the date by setting the corresponding TimeZone to dateFormatter

2.Set the Local TimeZone to dateFormatter, and form dateString from date

```
NSString *dateString = @"04/16/13 11:12:00";

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",localDateString);
```